# How do I make a 4-bit comparator?

Tags: comparator, logic-gates, alu

I'm making an ALU (Arithmetic and Logic Unit), I've made a 1-bit ALU with ease, but 1-bit (1b) is impractical, who would need only 1b? I've made that adder/subtractor and I need the comparator (multiplication/division is insane), I don't know how to make a 4b comparator (obviously). Please help!
EDIT: I have found a PURE 4b comparator, that uses 1b comparators:
[Valid XHTML http://www.setupsolution.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Magnitude-Comparator.jpg](http://www.setupsolution.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Magnitude-Comparator.jpg)
Thanks to the people that helped!

Answer (score 3):

In the architectures I've looked at, the addition/subtraction operation usually sets some bits in a FLAGS or STATUS register, indicating certain conditions of the result. For example, there's often a flag bit indicating the result of the last operation was zero, or the result of the last operation was less than zero.

Notice these two flags are easilly generated with a single wide-fan-in NOR gate, and by simply checking the sign bit of the result, respectively.

The comparison operation is typically done by executing a subtraction, and throwing away the result, just leaving the FLAGS registe affected by the operation.

Comment: I don't want 50 registers in my ALU, I want a comparator that uses it's own hardware, not the subtraction system, and I don't like unnecessary bits stored, so thanks for the answer, but it's not much help.

Comment: I'm only suggesting two bits, not 50 registers. Why so anxious about adding one register but willing to duplicate a bunch of ALU logic to replicate the subtraction function and call it a comparator?

Comment: First, you would need to store 4 bits, second the main concern I'm having would be that the adder/subtractor would be used A LOT, so you would have a serious heating issue, making the comparator run on that, too would melt something. PS don't suggest a fan, the ALU would be mostly enclosed, so unless I use paper, I'm not going to be able to cool it very well.

Comment: Two bits: Zero and Less-than-zero.

Comment: If you just want bitwise equal or not-equal between two arguments, you just need XOR gates. But that's not what's usually called a comparator in the the processor-architecture world.

Comment: @EnderScythe I somehow doubt that you would have any heating issues at all - unless you are trying to run at 1GHz or something like that. In fact by reusing the existing logic as a whole you'll be reducing the overall power consumption by having fewer ICs.

Answer (score 2):

The [74LS181](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls181.pdf) is a bit slice 4-bit arithmetic logic unit (ALU), and was the first complete ALU on a single chip.  It was used as the arithmetic/logic core in the CPUs of many historically significant minicomputers such s the PDP-11 and VAX-11/780.  The CPUs used as many as was necessary to implement their data size, i.e. there were four ALU chips in the PDP-11.

It implemented the following arithmetic operations:

```
Addition
Subtraction
Shift operand one bit
Magnitude comparison
plus 12 more
```

It also implemented several logic operations:

```
Exclusive OR
Comparator
AND, NAND, OR, NOR
plus 10 more
```

[image]

Here is the logic diagram.  It used 75 gates.

[image]

By the way they're still available from some distributors such as Newark and Mouser.

Comment: I asked for a comparator, not a complete ALU, thanks for the schematic, and the slice of history, though. (:

Comment: @EnderScythe  You said you were making an ALU, and since this schematic includes a comparator as part of its functionality I thought it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [74HC85](http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/74HC_HCT85_CNV.pdf) 4-bit magnitude comparator.

Comment: I'm still fairly new to logic gates, could you show me what the IA<B, IA=B and the IA>B inputs are used for?

Comment: They're used for cascading. For using a single unit IA = B should be 1 and the other two 0 (hard wired). See Figure 7 in the Philips datasheet.

Comment: Could you give me a better explanation?